# prove that $f$ is a diffeomorphism and an isometry

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $S_1 : [0, 2\pi r]\times [0, h]$

$S_2: x^2+y^2=r^2$

Let $f: S_1 \to S_2$

$(u,v)=(r\cos (\frac{u}{r}), r\sin (\frac{u}{r}), v)$ for $v\in [0,h]$ and $u\in [0, 2\pi r)$

How do I prove that $f$ is a diffeomorphism and $f$ is an isometry?

[image]

---

I know that the following theorem;

$f$ isometry $\iff$ for $S_1$ and $S_2$, the surface patches have the same first fundamental form.

But I don't know how to show these. Please can you help me. Thank you.

---

The definition of isomorphism: let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two regular surfaces. Let $f: S_1 \to S_2$ be diffeomorphism. $f$ is isometry if the length of $\gamma$ in $S_1$ must be equal to the length of $f\circ \gamma$ in $S_2$  for any curve $\gamma$ in $S_1$. i.e $L_{S_1}(\gamma )= L_{S_2}(f \circ \gamma )$

---

The definition of difeomorphsim: $f:S_1\to S_2$ is a diffeomorphism

if

(1) $f$ is smooth.

(2) $f$ is one to ne and onto.

(3) $f^{-1} :S_2\to S_1$ is smooth.

Comment: $f$ is not a diffeomorphism because it is not a homeomorphism. It is then also not an isometry.

Comment: But Dear @DanielRust , there should exist an diffeomorphism and isomorphism :( since my instructor said so. This is not homework or else. This is an example to explain the topic.

Comment: Is it possible they meant *local* diffeomorphism and *local* isometry?

Comment: These were not stated. I took and posted the photo of my notebook. @DanielRust

Comment: In fact, as given, $f$ isn't even a well-defined function because we don't know what happens to the element $(2\pi r,h)$ (one assumes that these elements are mapped to the same points that $(0,h)$ are mapped to, but this is not made explicit).

Comment: Perhaps you should give the definitions that you've been given for these terms. It's possible that your instructor has simply dropped the 'local' part of the names.

Comment: Well, I understand Dear @DanielRust I posted the second photo. What do you think about? I am student. And I am not good at the topic now. I am just trying to understand and learn. So I asked. Can you give me an explanation for the second example.

Comment: Could you put the definitions for 'diffeomorphism' and 'isometry' in to your post please? They have fairly standard definitions, but it's possible you're not using the standard ones (in fact for diffeomorphism you are definitely not using the usual definition)

Comment: The definion of isomorphism: let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two regular surfaces. Let $f: S_1 \to S_2$ be diffeomorphism. $f$ is isometry if the length of $\gamma$ in $S_1$ must be equal to the length of $f\circ \gamma$ in $S_2$  for any curve $\gamma$ in $S_1$. i.e $L_{S_1}(\gamma )= L_{S_2}(f \circ \gamma )$

Comment: The definition of difeomorphsim: $f:S_1\to S_2$ is a diffeomorphism if $f$ is smooth. $f$ is one to ne and onto. $f^{-1} :S_2\to S_1$ is smooth.

Comment: I wrote two definitons. If you explain these two example, I'll be happy. Dear @DanieLRust

Comment: Ok, it's pretty clear that $f$ is not a diffeomorphism from the (standard) definition you've given because, if we extend the definition of $f$ to the whole of $S_1$, then it is not one to one as $f(0,h)=f(2\pi r,h)$, and if we don't extend , but just let $S_1=[0,2\pi r)\times [0,h]$ then $f$ does not have a smooth inverse (it doesn't even have a continuous inverse).

Comment: Okay I understand now. Thank you. Well, what is your opinion about the second example? How can I show the isometry? @DanielRust